# Should the break be within the conditional block, our outside?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, conditional-statements, break

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
switch (key) {
case RIGHT:
case d:
  if (collisionState.right.isSolid === false) {
    ++mapState.mapOffsetX;
    mapState.modX = 1;
    mapState.moveDirection = 'right';
    break; 
  }
...
...
...
```

Above, I have placed the break within the conditional statement. However, the break could have easily been placed outside of the conditional statement as well.

In this circumstance, where is the best location for the break?

Comment: What is the circumstance for the break? Do you want to fall through to the next case statement if this case's if is not evaluated?

Comment: what happen if `collisionState.right.isSolid` is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break` will exit the switch statement. So if you want to stop going down the list of `case`'s regardless of the result of the `if` then you want the `break` outside the `if`.

Instead if you want to continue following down the `case` list, then leave the `break` inside the `if`.